Newton's Method on $f(x)=x^k$
I am currently learning about Newton's method concerning multiple roots and convergence.

Newton's method's sequence of approximations on $f(x) = x^k$ with $k > 1$ using
$x_0\not=0$.

I need to determine what the sequence converges to and then figure out where it converges linearly or quadratically.
Would it be correct to say that $x^k$ has a root of $0$ of multiplicity $k$. Therefore does not have a simple root and thus cannot converge quadratically so it will converge locally.
I am still confused about how to determine if it convergences linearly or quadratically and then how that relates to having multiple roots in this case. So I am not sure if I am thinking this correctly or if I'm on the right path. I would really appreciate any help

Newton's method uses the update rule:
$
x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}
$
Applying Newton's Method
For $ f(x) = x^k $, we have:
$
f(x) = x^k, \quad f'(x) = kx^{k-1}
$
Thus, Newton's method becomes:
$
x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{x_n^k}{k x_n^{k-1}}
$
Simplifying the right-hand side:
$
x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{x_n^k}{k x_n^{k-1}} = x_n - \frac{x_n}{k} = \left(1 - \frac{1}{k}\right) x_n
$
So, the iteration update is:
$
x_{n+1} = \frac{k-1}{k} x_n
$
This means that each new approximation is a fraction $ \frac{k-1}{k} $ of the previous one.
Convergence
For $ f(x) = x^k $, the root at $ x = 0 $ has multiplicity k, meaning that it is not a simple root. In cases where the root is simple, Newton's method typically converges quadratically. However, when the root has multiplicity greater than 1, the convergence behavior changes.
In fact, for a root of multiplicity k , Newton's method converges linearly, not quadratically. This happens because when you have a multiple root, Newton's method slows down its convergence, as seen in the formula above. Specifically:

The ratio $ \frac{k-1}{k} $ appears in each step, meaning the difference between successive approximations is reduced by this constant factor, leading to linear convergence.
Quadratic convergence would occur if the error decreased at a rate proportional to the square of the previous error. But here, the error only decreases by a constant proportion $ \frac{k-1}{k} $ at each step, indicating linear convergence.

Summary

The sequence converges to $ x = 0 $,
The convergence is linear, not quadratic, due to the multiple root of $ x = 0 $ with multiplicity k.

